# Both reCaptcha v2 and v3 on same page

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

as I understand, it seems to be possible to use both v2 and v3 on the same page (see https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/279), but can't find any example of it :/

I already have HTML pages with invisible v2, and first, I want to evaluate the accuracy of the v3 score without breaking my current v2 (v3 will be only for test purposes). I was also wondering if it could be possible to use v3 and render v2 challenges for low scores.

Any idea ?

(sorry for my english, it's not my mother tongue ;)

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: made it work? I need same functionality

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this explains how : [Can I run reCAPTCHA v2 and v3 on the same page?](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-run-recaptcha-v2-and-v3-on-the-same-page)

Worked well with two v3 and one v2 checkbox on the same page.

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with linking to a solution, please make sure to add context to your answer, so that it does not rely solely on the link.

Comment: The above linked answer has been removed from the Google reCaptcha FAQs page. Here are existing solutions: https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/279, https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module/pull/70, https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module/issues/68, https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/152.

Answer (score 2):

The following example (written by [Anton Cherniavskyi](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/279#issuecomment-445529732)) works.

However, I think it only works with `v2 invisible` + `v3`, ie.: You **can't** use `v2 checkbox` + `v3`.

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=v2_onload"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=v3_onload&render=V3_SITE_KEY"></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible" data-sitekey="V2_INVISIBLE_SITE_KEY" data-callback="v2_callback"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function v2_onload() { console.log('v2 loaded'); }
    function v3_onload() { console.log('v3 loaded'); }
    function v2_callback(token) { console.log('v2 token: ' + token); }
    function v3_callback(token) { console.log('v3 token: ' + token); }

    // call these manually
    function test_v2() { grecaptcha.execute(); }
    function test_v3() { grecaptcha.execute(V3_SITE_KEY/*, {action: '...'}*/).then(v3_callback); }
</script>
```